# Facebook comments subscribe to thread/conversation via API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, comments

I am using the new facebook comments module, and I am intersted in subscribing a user to a conversation via the API. I am referring to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/Comment/ but this doesnt seem to have an API call for a user to subscribe to a conversation. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The comment plugin has subscribe options for each item in the thread for the users. That would be the easiest for the user.  Their currently isn't a documented API method for this.  You could build something yourself manually, and while possible, it will have the problem that you won't be able to notify them very easily like Facebook allows with the red notification api (you would have to resort to emailing them or something similar). You would also need them to authenticate your application and prompt for various extended permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was thinking along the same lines, maybe to subscribe to the comment.create event and notify the user via email or post to their wall.